# ¿Se puede hacer un login y registro de usuario al mismo tiempo en Laravel 7?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

estoy realizando un sistema en laravel en el cual tengo que utilizar un login dado que estoy utilizando un web service para poder recuperar los usuarios. tengo el login me da acceso pero se podrá realizar tambien el registro al mismo tiempo que se esta logeando es decir en la vista del login se guarden esos mismos datos?
se me esta complicando por como estoy obteniendo los usuarios ya que hay que darle roles y permisos a usuarios especificos.
espero me puedan ayudar ! GRACIAS.

Comment: Asumo que estas preguntando si se puede usar la misma pagina para logearse y registrarse verdad? como lo harian varias pagina web?

Comment: asi es. disculpa soy algo nueva en este ambiente!

Comment: Lo que quieres sera algo como este [ejemplo](https://codepen.io/FlorinPop17/pen/vPKWjd), puedes guiarte de este mismo, solo tienes que crear tu index.blade.php y aqui crear dos forms uno para tu login y otro para register, estos dos tienen que hacer post a sus rutas respectivas o sus funciones respectivas, lo demas es parte de html, css, javascript

Comment: Recuerda hacer 2 form para tu login, un form para iniciar sesión y otro para registrarse (bueno, si es que necesitas un [ejemplo](https://codepen.io/FlorinPop17/pen/vPKWjd?editors=1100) así).

Comment: lo que necesito saber es más si se puede hacer el registro y el login al mismo tiempo !! será posible ?

Comment: Si, cuando haces un login lo que recuperas es un token con las propiedades del usuario, entonces cuando haces el registro tambien devuelves un token con las propiedades del usuario y haces el push a la base de datos

Comment: Si se puede ... pero eso es como para un tutorial... aqui no podemos pasarte una respuesta ...